# React App.tsx Expression Expected in script tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, error-handling

So I am having this issue where I am building a React App using typescript. I am using Bulma, the css library and I copy and pasted vanilla javascript. However, I keep getting an error here:

````
<script>
const $navbarBurgers``` where it is a ts1109 error saying expression expected. Also, even if I add a type to it, the error still persists. What is going on?


```<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

// Get all "navbar-burger" elements
const $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger'), 0);

// Check if there are any navbar burgers
if ($navbarBurgers.length > 0) {

  // Add a click event on each of them
  $navbarBurgers.forEach( el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {

      // Get the target from the "data-target" attribute
      const target = el.dataset.target;
      const $target = document.getElementById(target);

      // Toggle the "is-active" class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
      el.classList.toggle('is-active');
      $target.classList.toggle('is-active');

    });
  });
}

});

</script>
````

Comment: Do you have the open script tag? **<script >**

Comment: @NachoZullo, I am sorry about that, it is not open. I fixed it above.